# Função Keyboard.dismiss() não funciona

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou tentando fazer com que o teclado virtual desapareça quando pressionado qualquer parte da tela no React Native, porém não funciona.

Já tentei colocar esta função nas views, texts e até mesmo criar uma constante por fora com `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, mas nada, o que posso fazer?

```
export default function StatusFile() {
const searchBar = React.createRef();
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

return(
    <View style={styles.container} onPress={**() => Keyboard.dismiss()**}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
            <SearchBar 
                text={search}
                ref={searchBar}
                placeholder='Procurar...'
                barStyle='black'    
                textFieldBackgroundColor='#FF8C00'
                onChangeText={setSearch}
                onSearchButtonPress={() => searchBar.current.blur()}
            />

            {search !== '' ?  
            statusFile.filter(a => a.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1).map(a => (
                <Text style={styles.texto} key={a}>
                    {a}
                </Text>
            ))
            : 
            <Text style={styles.texto}>Faça uma busca pelo status, EX: 10</Text>
            }  
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O elemento `<View>` não possui uma propriedade `onPress`. Você pode remover a `<View>` e utilizar apenas a `<ScrollView>`, ocupando a tela inteira.

A propriedade [`keyboardShouldPersistTaps`](http://keyboardShouldPersistTaps) da `<ScrollView>` determina quando o teclado deve permanecer visível após um toque. Os valores possíveis são:

- `'never'`: É o comportamento padrão. Tocar fora de uma entrada de texto faz com que o teclado seja fechado e o componente tocado não receba o toque. Por exemplo, se o teclado estiver aberto e um botão for tocado, o teclado é fechado e nada mais acontece.
- `'always'`: O teclado não será fechado automaticamente e a `<ScrollView>` não capturará toques, mas os filhos poderão capturá-los. Por exemplo, se o teclado estiver aberto e um botão for tocado, o teclado permanece aberto e o botão executará o `onPress`.
- `'handled'`: O teclado não será fechado automaticamente quando o toque for capturado por filhos da `<ScrollView>` (ou se o toque for capturado por um ancestral). Caso o toque não seja capturado por nenhum elemento, o teclado é fechado.

No seu caso, `'never'` ou `'handled'` podem servir, a depender do seu comportamento desejado. Por exemplo:

```
<ScrollView style={styles.scroll} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
  // ...
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Rafael, muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema e também mostrou que preciso me aprofundar mais nas propriedades dos elementos que eu uso, um abraço.